# few/fewer (Fewer birds came this year.)

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

Fewer birds came this year.

Does the above sentence say that more birds came last year than this year?
Could someone please explain whether the comparative adjective,'fewer' actually describes 'this year ' or 'birds'?

Answer (score 2):

Adjectives usually modify what they are next to.

In this case, fewer modifies birds, not years.